# How to run action after git pull on client side?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm looking a way to automatise git pull on client side.this clone is on an isolated server Only reachable via vpn. So which kind of hook can I use to detect pushed content on the github repo and pull this on the cloned one ?

Thanks

EDIT: to clarify, I've a LAMP Server and a Github repo. When I push a commit to Github from my local machine, I would the LAMP server "auto" pull code from github. But this kind of hook seem to be only available on server side (Github), not client (LAMP). Is it more clarified ?

Comment: Please clarify a bit what you want to do. Are you trying to synchronize an internal mirror with an external one?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to poll Github to check if a new commit came (you can do it with `git fetch` if you don't want to do `git pull` for some reason).

Comment: This is what I meant : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)
You need to send a request every hour (for example) to check if Github gets a new commit.

Comment: ok. I think that a git hook can do that , but I don't know which one on client side..